# How to scroll in an undefined height div

Tags: css, user-interface, materialize

I am currently trying to make a clean messaging system, and I have an issue with my interface. Note that I am making it with **Materialize**, but I can tweak it with custom CSS. I have a list of message on the left side, and the remaining space on the right displays the selected message. Those two items are side by side. Pretty classic.

But I have an issue when there are too many messages on the list, or when the text is too long to fit in the view height, I can't scroll.

I need the page to be non-scrollable, but I also need to be able to scroll the list and the message view.

To so, I tried to do something like that:

```
.message-view {
    height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It works, but it is not what I want. I want the `.message-view` div to take the entire remaining height. I could make tricky calculation based on previous elements heights, but I find it pretty annoying, and I am not sure I could get the exact height right on every device that way.

**TLDR: I want a div that would be taking the remaining height dynamically to be scrollable using CSS or Materialize. Any idea?**

Here is an example of my issue (on the left, the list is scrollable but height is garbage, 
arbitrarily set to 80vh because it is approximately the height), and the message-view is not scrollable):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.message-list-scroller {
  width: 30%;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message-list { 
  width: 98%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.message-list-item {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.message-view {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

<h1>Message page</h1>

<div class="content">

  <div class="message-list-scroller">
  <div class="message-list">
    <div class="message-list-item">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Preview of the message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message-list-item">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Preview of the message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message-list-item">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Preview of the message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message-list-item">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Preview of the message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message-list-item">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Preview of the message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="message-view">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a metus vitae risus eleifend vulputate. Etiam porttitor turpis nec massa porta interdum. Maecenas euismod, quam euismod interdum venenatis, metus ex placerat mi, vitae mattis elit tellus id libero. Mauris molestie ac mauris sit amet vulputate. Aenean et dui in turpis facilisis faucibus vitae quis neque. Fusce faucibus scelerisque nunc. In efficitur odio nulla, eu mollis ligula pulvinar non. Phasellus imperdiet nunc velit, eget posuere dui tempus vel. Nullam semper, metus id luctus sollicitudin, nibh tellus volutpat urna, et aliquam tortor velit a arcu. Maecenas mauris dolor, vehicula non tellus eu, luctus molestie libero. Aenean vestibulum et ipsum in ultrices. Pellentesque nec vulputate nisi.
Pellentesque luctus justo erat, pulvinar placerat sapien malesuada sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In malesuada dui in quam sagittis varius. Aenean commodo dictum erat sed tincidunt. Nunc hendrerit dapibus neque vitae dictum. Aenean lacinia dolor nec ante imperdiet condimentum. Vestibulum bibendum cursus nibh, elementum tempor magna congue nec. In sed justo vel nulla rhoncus ultrices. Ut porta congue sem semper rutrum. Aenean dapibus massa metus, eu pellentesque nibh congue eu. Morbi efficitur sit amet massa a tincidunt. Praesent maximus quam sit amet nulla mattis, a sagittis velit efficitur.
Aliquam sed lectus accumsan, feugiat nisl nec, vestibulum orci. Maecenas aliquet at dui sed consectetur. Sed ornare et ligula a posuere. Integer elementum quis libero non rutrum. Vestibulum maximus eros in enim ullamcorper, sed maximus libero consectetur. Fusce ut nulla ultrices, malesuada risus eu, fermentum est. Praesent lectus quam, cursus vel lacus vitae, luctus malesuada mauris.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras lacinia fringilla risus, sit amet gravida urna maximus gravida. Etiam tincidunt auctor fermentum. In non vehicula urna. Mauris turpis diam, facilisis vitae congue at, malesuada ac augue. Praesent augue nibh, ullamcorper id ultrices commodo, ornare in nisi. Pellentesque nunc mauris, fringilla eget accumsan sed, congue nec diam. Curabitur viverra erat ipsum, ut cursus dui fermentum vel. Nam luctus tellus non elit tristique vehicula. Sed mattis eu justo a varius. Integer metus lacus, mattis quis elit id, euismod tincidunt est. Mauris porttitor eros nec risus facilisis posuere. Sed pharetra, felis in commodo tincidunt, nisi purus lobortis elit, rutrum varius nisi mauris ac arcu. Mauris nec odio sed mauris condimentum ultrices sit amet quis purus. Mauris dictum metus sit amet ante gravida aliquet eu sit amet mi.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam at arcu sit amet nunc feugiat fermentum. Duis id mi dui. Cras molestie nec quam sit amet convallis. Sed et mauris augue. Curabitur sodales ipsum lacinia convallis vestibulum. Nullam commodo urna eget nibh consequat auctor.
Nulla facilisi. Quisque ultrices rutrum erat, nec pretium nulla. Aliquam vulputate molestie scelerisque. Suspendisse eu interdum erat, quis dapibus neque. Donec ac pellentesque libero. Nulla erat odio, mattis non dolor ac, pellentesque sollicitudin nunc. Nulla ultrices ac ligula a feugiat. Morbi euismod mauris dolor, eu finibus orci condimentum et. Integer ac dui vel mauris ultrices mattis sit amet a magna. Mauris urna neque, faucibus non erat a, mattis molestie odio. Cras in elit tellus. Donec cursus ultricies sollicitudin. Nullam sed mi tincidunt, dignissim dolor at, suscipit tortor. Donec tortor neque, auctor a tincidunt eget, consequat sit amet eros. Nulla interdum, justo in blandit rutrum, urna nisl molestie urna, in lacinia nisi massa in odio. Pellentesque sodales massa nec pulvinar mattis.
Fusce a consectetur mi, nec egestas nibh. Etiam purus nisi, scelerisque sit amet tempus vitae, blandit at risus. Fusce posuere imperdiet viverra. Quisque vel suscipit turpis. Fusce dapibus non sem eget mollis. Morbi tincidunt lorem a mattis pretium. Duis nunc eros, malesuada id mi non, euismod bibendum tortor. Nulla augue lectus, porttitor ac lectus a, placerat congue sem. Vestibulum blandit lectus at urna vestibulum sodales. Curabitur malesuada tempor justo id varius. Pellentesque posuere sed erat ac iaculis.
Sed ac imperdiet mi, sit amet sodales sapien. Morbi enim neque, aliquet eget venenatis vitae, tincidunt vitae lectus. Cras pellentesque condimentum eros vel euismod. Nunc posuere magna augue, sit amet pulvinar orci auctor vitae. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque id auctor enim, nec sollicitudin lectus. In in pharetra odio, nec blandit diam. Integer vulputate lectus id lectus ultricies pellentesque. Donec a ornare leo, vel egestas lacus. Sed in libero laoreet, posuere sapien ac, ornare felis. Curabitur vel facilisis nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum purus sem, bibendum id urna sit amet, iaculis vehicula elit. Cras porttitor urna in diam accumsan eleifend.
Vestibulum magna lectus, venenatis sed venenatis dictum, hendrerit eu arcu. Praesent sed orci id sapien scelerisque ultrices vitae non ante. Donec dignissim magna et rhoncus suscipit. Donec ut hendrerit risus, eget luctus mi. Maecenas vulputate aliquet efficitur. Donec consectetur fermentum magna, a viverra sapien semper ac. Curabitur in lacus eu sapien porta placerat non quis metus. Aenean viverra velit id erat iaculis fringilla. Duis ultrices sollicitudin venenatis. Aliquam id cursus diam.
Curabitur neque lacus, lobortis non massa sed, facilisis luctus ipsum. Nullam eget semper turpis. Sed a lorem vel arcu tempor bibendum. Praesent sem tellus, placerat sit amet est vel, ultrices porttitor sem. Cras egestas pharetra metus, nec aliquam diam consequat vitae. Ut nec ullamcorper tortor. Vestibulum dignissim nisi sit amet interdum rutrum. Integer aliquet lectus id lacus vehicula, sit amet blandit arcu fringilla. Etiam mattis bibendum tristique. Aenean sit amet ultricies odio, eu gravida ante. In vel leo id lacus volutpat accumsan vitae non nulla. Quisque eu rhoncus magna, nec molestie nibh. Nam viverra posuere est ut egestas. Nunc mauris nibh, vulputate sed viverra tincidunt, faucibus condimentum mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Quisque diam velit, suscipit ac nisi sit amet, convallis egestas metus.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in the provided snippet the message-view is next to the message-list-scroller, this is unwanted behaviour?, the question is a little unclear if you ask me

Comment: I will edit that then, but yes the message-view should be on the right and the list on the left, they should be side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the crass example here - but:

**1) create a page container, set to `100vh` and `overflow:hidden`.**

**2) Use the grid system to make your two columns. Set these also to `height:100vh`.**

**3) Inside these cols, place a `.scrollable` div with a `max-height` of `100vh`.**

```
<div class="messages">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col m4">
      <ul class="scrollable">...</ul>     
    </div>
    <div class="col m8">
      <div class="scrollable">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.messages {
  height:100vh;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col.m4 {
  background-color: white;
}

.col.m8, col.m4 {
  height:100vh;
}

.scrollable {
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/eYJmBYo).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. You missed a point, which is that our scrollable area is not 100vh. It has some undefined height content before, that is what I tried to represent in my exemple with the "Message" title on top of the scroll list.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without an explicit height. Very easy to do the calculation on the fly though.